# String Comparison in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

Trying to create a dictionary function, first I made a two dimensional table:

```
dictionary = {}
for i = 1, 52 do
  dictionary[i] = {}
end
```

Then I read in from a txt file words into the dictionary table which has 26 entries for uppercase and likewise for lowercase.

When I try to search through the table to compare words I'm having some difficulty:

```
test = dictionary[1][176]
testTwo = "Ave"

if test == testTwo then print("The strings are the same") else print("They are not the same)
end
```

I know that at dictionary[1][176] is "Ave" but when I try to do any comparisons they will not be equal.

In reply to the answers this is how I am reading in the dictionary:

```
function CreateDictionary()

  io.input("dictionary.txt")
  dictionary = {}
  for line in io.lines() do
    print(type(line))
    table.insert(dictionary, line)
  end
end
```

Comment: How are you reading the words? Are you absolutely certain that `dictionary[1][176] == "Ave"`?

Comment: Before the string comparison, did you try `print(dictionary[1][176])` and see what the result is?

Comment: Yes and it comes out to "Ave". I also tested to make sure it was a string with type() and indeed it is a string. I am just not sure how we are adding words to the table incorrectly

Comment: Your code seems too complex. What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need a 2-dimensional table when you can efficiently index a 1-dimensional one with the strings read?

Comment: The dictionary is just a text file filled with words. When I search for a word I was trying to separate the words by starting letter. Would one large table with all the words be better?

Comment: I agree with lhf about complexity. And it's still not clear what you're trying to do: are you create a binary search tree? How do you plan on using such data structure, to do what?

Comment: A simpler dictionary reader has been added. But still the same problem.

the first word in the list is "ACM" 
test = "ACM"
if test == dictionary[1] then print("they are the same")

still not working.

Comment: I used your newest code, can't reproduce the problem. It prints the same for me.

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't set `dictionary[1][176]` to `Ave`, because when I run this piece of code I get `The strings are the same`.

To set it `Ave` you would do something like that:

```
dictionary[1][176] = "Ave"
```

Comment: See edited post for more info on how we entered the data into the table